# What is the C++ equivalent of this C code

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to learn how to access `c++` library from `c`, I understood I've to use `extern "C"`, in order to test it, I started with the below working `c` code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void c_free_string(const char *str){
    free(str);
}

char *concat(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    char *res;
    const char del[] = ", ";
    res = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + strlen(del) + 1);
    if (!res) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed: insufficient memory!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    strcpy(res, str1);
    strcat(res, del);
    strcat(res, str2);

    printf("Result: '%s'\n", res);
    return res;
}

int main(void) {
    const char str1[] = "First";
    const char str2[] = "Second";
    char* s = concat(str1, str2);
    printf("Result: '%s'\n", s);
    c_free_string(s);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

1. I wanted to write the equivalent `c++` code of the above
2. I want to be ensure using the correct declaration to be able to do c binding with the lib generated from this `c++` code.

I started with the belowm but stuck:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

extern "C"
void c_free_string(const char *str){
    free(str);
}
extern "C"
char *concat(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    std::cout << "Hello from C++";
    stringstream ss;
    ss << str1 << ", " << str2;
    string res = ss.str();

    std::cout << "Result: "<<res;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Your C code isn't quite valid C code. In particular, `c_free_string` should take a `char *`, not a `const char *`, and in `concat`, you should do `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` instead of `return EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by equivalent C++? C is almost a subset of C++, so if you make the two changes in my last comment, and also change `res = malloc(` to `res = (char*) malloc(`, then your program will be simultaneously valid C and valid C++.

Comment: When you have to call C++ code from C, you need to put it into a wrapper where just the header is enclosed in `extern C` declaration to avoid mangling while the body has to be regular C++ function.  And that piece needs to be compiled with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Also, do not try to mix `new/delete` with `malloc/free`.

Comment: @unxnut code example pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, the answer looks to be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

extern "C"
void c_free_string(char *str){
    free(str);
}
extern "C"
char *concat(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    printf("welcome from c++\n");
    char *res;
    const char del[] = ", ";
    res = (char*) malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + strlen(del) + 1);
    if (!res) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed: insufficient memory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(res, str1);
    strcat(res, del);
    strcat(res, str2);

    printf("Result: '%s'\n", res);
    return res;
}
```

**UODATE**

A cleaner version based on [Paul McKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie) feedback:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

extern "C"
void c_free_string(char *str){
    delete [] str;
}

extern "C"
char *concat(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    const char* del = ", ";
    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(del);
    int len3 = strlen(str2);
    char *res = new char [len1 + len2 + len3 + 1]{};
    strcpy(res, str1);
    strcpy(res + len1, del);
    strcpy(res + len1 + len2, str2);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    char *test = concat("abc", "123");
    std::cout << test;
    c_free_string(test);
}
```

Comment: Since you want to write this in C++, why do you need to call `malloc` and `free`?  The calling code shouldn't care how the memory was allocated.  The traditional `new[]` and `delete[]` could have been used.

Comment: Also, `#include <cstring>` and `#include <cstdio>` are missing.  [Here is a cleaner version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/604d85234a57a6f4).  Note the use of `strcpy` on all three C-style strings.  Using `strcat` means that the position of the last terminating null has to be searched each time `strcat` is called.  Recording the length of the strings,  the starting position of each `strcpy` is set up already, making the code run faster.  You could even make it more efficient by using `strncpy`, since you know the lengths already.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie deeply appreciated